# how to wrap only left side content

Tags: css, styled-components

I have trouble with css. Currently trying to achieve 2 things.

1. I need for text to always be aligned with navbar first item. No matter the browser width Showned in pictures.
   [image: example1].
   [image: Example2]
2. I need to make image entire right side to be fullWidth. So it's width should be same width the same as navbar background. Basically width should be entire right side.

I tried using wrappers. But this does not seem like wrapper will be a correct fix here. To be honest I think I lack specific knowledge to solve this issue. So I was unable to generate and try new ideas.

Image vizualization
[image]

```
export const NavbarWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-left: 24px;
`;


const ContainerStyled = styled.div`
  .content_container {
    display: flex;
  }

  .img {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ContainerStyled>
      <Navbar />
      <NavbarWrapper>
        <div className="content_container">
          <p className="title">
            This should be responsive to navbar on all sizes
          </p>
          <img className="img" src="/image.jpg" alt="grey bridge" />
        </div>
      </NavbarWrapper>
    </ContainerStyled>
  );
}
```

Reproducable [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-dewdney-j6poss?file=/src/App.tsx) For inspecting I suggest clicking third button on codeSandbox browser for better viewing experience.

Comment: I think you already achieved the first one

Comment: Yes I did that. However I need to achieve first and second point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution where the **Wrapper** component has a grid. So, idea is to create 3 columns and put the content in only 2 and 3 columns. Also, limit the image view to 2 columns.

[image]

##### Wrapper.tsx

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const NavbarWrapper = styled.div`
  min-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(320px, 600px) 1fr;
`;
```

##### App.tsx

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Navbar } from "./navbar/Navbar";
import { NavbarWrapper } from "./Wrapper";
import "./styles.css";

const ContainerStyled = styled.div`
  .content_container {
    display: flex;
    grid-column: 2 / 2 span;
  }
  .img {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 calc(100% - 29vmin);
    max-height: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
`;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ContainerStyled>
      <Navbar />
      <NavbarWrapper>
        <div className="content_container">
          <p className="title">
            This should be responsive to navbar on all sizes
          </p>
          <img className="img" src="/image.jpg" alt="grey bridge" />
        </div>
      </NavbarWrapper>
    </ContainerStyled>
  );
}
```

And finally, we need to add one property `grid-column: 2;` to the **Navbar** to keep the navigation link centered.

##### Navbar.tsx

```css
ul {
  grid-column: 2; /* new line */
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: A grid based solution like this is definitely the cleanest solution imo.

Comment: Yep, this is the best solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified wrapper.tsx as follows:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const NavbarWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 24px;
`;
```

and App.tsx as follows:

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Navbar } from "./navbar/navbar";
import { NavbarWrapper } from "./wrappers";

const ContainerStyled = styled.div`
  .content_container {
    display: grid;
  }
  .title {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .img {
    width: 100%;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 6;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ContainerStyled>
      <Navbar />
      <NavbarWrapper>
        <div className="content_container">
          <p className="title">
            This should be responsive to navbar on all sizes
          </p>
          <img className="img" src="/image.jpg" alt="grey bridge" />
        </div>
      </NavbarWrapper>
    </ContainerStyled>
  );
}
```

Check following Sandbox: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-pine-6gs99s?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Good try, however I need to have navbar unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I've displayed image as background image and also wrapped the `image div` inside another div i.e. `imgContainer div`. Wrote some `media queries` for handing smaller screen widths.

Final ScreenShot -
[image]

You can find the code sandbox link here - [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-hill-ur09ky?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Yes, this solutions actually works. However looks a bit hacky. Such as parent containers are smaller than child container. And using media query to adjust min-width a couple percentages, leaves a lot of devices looking incorrectly. Still this is the best solution so far.

Comment: Yup, this would downside of this technique but I tried to adjust the width with some common devices.